Are there any useful convexity properties of quantum dynamical semigroups?
I'm am wondering if there are any useful properties of quantum dynamical semigroups I can exploit for convex/concave optimization with respect to the semigroup parameter. A proper definition of a quantum dynamical semigroup can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Markov_semigroup. For the purposes of this question though, they are collections of completely positive linear maps of the form $e^{t \mathcal{L}}$, where $t \geq 0$ is a real number and $\mathcal{L}$ is the semigroup generator. Completely positive means that the extended map $1 \otimes e^{t \mathcal{L}}$ maps positive matrices to positive matrices.
Given some initial positive matrix $\rho_0$, I am interested in finding values of $t$ which optimize convex/concave functions of $\rho(t) = e^{t \mathcal{L}}[\rho_0]$. For example, if $f$ is a convex function, under what conditions is it true that $\mathrm{Tr}[f(\rho(t))]$ is convex in $t$? Are there any useful theorems which characterize the convexity of these semigroups in this sense? What about particular cases like $f(x) = x^2$, $f(x) = \log(x)$, or $f(x) = x \log(x)$?
Thanks in advance!
Edit: this is a cross post from https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/38650/is-purity-convex-in-time
